# How to use pandas to create a crosstab to show the prediction result of random forest predictor?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

I'm a newbie to the random forest (as well as python). 
I'm using random forest classifier, the dataset is defined 't2002'.

```
 t2002.column
```

So here are the columns:

```
Index(['IndividualID', 'ES2000_B01ID', 'NSSec_B03ID', 'Vehicle', 
   'Age_B01ID',
   'IndIncome2002_B02ID', 'MarStat_B01ID', 'EcoStat_B03ID',
   'MainMode_B03ID', 'TripStart_B02ID', 'TripEnd_B02ID',
   'TripDisIncSW_B01ID', 'TripTotalTime_B01ID', 'TripTravTime_B01ID',
   'TripPurpFrom_B01ID', 'TripPurpTo_B01ID'],
  dtype='object')
```

I'm using codes as below to run the classifier:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_all = t2002.drop(['MainMode_B03ID'],axis=1)
y_all = t2002['MainMode_B03ID']
p = 0.2

X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all,y_all,test_size=p, 
random_state=23)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)

 parameters = {
         }    # parameter is blank

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring=acc_scorer)
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train,y_train)

clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,predictions))
```

In this case, how could I use pandas to generate a crosstab (like a table) to show the detailed prediction results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you explain what does the detailed prediction results include?

Comment: @Arihant it's like a confusion matrix to show the actual class and predicted class like the table here: https://python-data-science.readthedocs.io/en/latest/evaluation.html

Comment: Create a pandas dataframe using the predicted output and the true output. Then this link will help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a confusion matrix using sklearn and then convert it to pandas data frame.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
#creating confusion matrix as array
confusion = confusion_matrix(t2002['MainMode_B03ID'].tolist(),predictions)

#converting to df
new_df = pd.DataFrame(confusion,
                 index = t2002['MainMode_B03ID'].unique(),
                 columns = t2002['MainMode_B03ID'].unique())
```

Comment: This worked for me using my `y_test` and `y_pred` variables. How can I calculate percentages of `0 true|true` & `1 true|true`?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to show all the predicted results using pandas. Use `cv_results_` as described in [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_) # clf is the GridSearchCV object
print(results.head())
```